# Disabled validators losing content on postback

Tags: asp.net, validation

**Summary:**
Disabled ASP.NET validators are losing their `InnerHTML` content when posted-back to the server, and then when enabled (locally via JavaScript) show the `ErrorMessage` rather than original `InnerHTML` when fired.

**More Details:**
I deal with some complex forms that require lots of individual controls to be visible/invisible, and their validators to be enabled/disabled, depending on the selection of other controls.

All the validators contain an single "asterisk" image, with the error message shown via the central `asp:ValidatorSummary` object. For instance (formatted for viewing here, <strike>normally there is no whitespace</strike> **UPDATE**, this is not actually correct, please see update below)...

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="valName" 
  ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="Enter a name">
    <img runat="server" src="~/images/error.gif" />
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Rather than use `asp:CustomValidator` on every single validator (which requires local JavaScript and server-side handlers for each), I simply set `.enabled = false` on normal validators as part of the event handler for the "parent" control.  (The status of the controls is also set on the server-side on the initial page load, as well as subsequent post-back page loads.)

```
function showName(show){
  document.getElementById("txtName").style.display = (show ? "" : "none");
  document.getElementById("valName").enabled = show;
}
```

The problem lies in the sequence of events where a validator is disabled, the form is posted-back... then a control is changed (via user interation) and the validator is enabled.  If the validator now fails (on an attempted post-back) the `<img` code has gone, so instead it displays the `ErrorMessage` text where the image should be.

The `InnerHTML` remains as long as the validator stays enabled.

Other than dynamically adding the image to each validator on every single page load (which I *really* don't want to do), or converting them all to `CustomValidator`s (which again I *really* don't want to do), does anybody know any way around this?  Is this a known bug (because I can't find anything obvious)?

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 under Visual Studio 2010 - unfortunately, not in a position at the moment to upgrade to a higher version of ASP.NET.

**UPDATE**
I have just discovered is that the `<img` tag is actually preceded by a `&nbsp;` entity... and if I remove that, leaving just the `<img` tag within the validator, it works.

After lots of playing, from what I can work out if the `InnerHTML` of the validator contains just plain text (i.e. no ASP server-side controls) then the `InnerHTML` will persist across post-backs no matter whether the validator is enabled or not.

However, if the `InnerHTML` **starts with** any plain text (other than whitespace) AND also has any server-side controls, then it does NOT persist across post-backs correctly when the validator is disabled.

I don't understand why this is the case, but for the minor formatting issue I can certainly cope with it... either that, or I will have to put the `&nbsp;` inside a literal, or `style` the `<img` tag... plenty of different options on that one.

Using a ASP.NET 4.0 test-bed application, I can confirm that the same thing happens in that version.

If nobody had anything else they want to add in the next couple of days, I will "answer" the question myself with the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in my updated question, the reason for the issue was due to the `InnerHTML` of the validator starting with `&nbsp;` and then containing a server-side control.

Before I had it as...

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="valName" ControlToValidate="txtName"
  ErrorMessage="Enter a name">&nbsp;<img runat="server" src="~/images/error.gif" 
  /></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

To fix it, I simply removed the `&nbsp;`...

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="valName" ControlToValidate="txtName"
  ErrorMessage="Enter a name"><img runat="server" src="~/images/error.gif" 
  /></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Hopefully that will help somebody else, in the unlikely event that they find themselves in a situation situation.

As always, if somebody comes up with a different answer / solution, I'm always willing to reconsider my options.